# How can i solve fatal error: module 'package_name' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I've been dealing with this error for a long time, I tried many ways but none of them worked. I've listed the ways I've tried below. Please do not recommend them again. Thanks

```
The Error: /ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:12:9: fatal error: module 'admob_flutter' not found
    @import admob_flutter;
     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

Ways I've Tried

- cd ios -> pod clean -> pod deintegrate -> pod install -> pod update
- I open XCode with .xcworkspace and build again
- delete Podfile.lock and Pods file after that reinstall pods
- And of course flutter clean -> flutter pub get

Comment: One thing not on your list is cleaning the Derived Data folder, this is often the cure when working with swift projects but maybe it is also useful for flutter projects

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Flutter app, the target iOS version is set to 9.0. Most common plugins would have a minimum version higher than 9.0. If you add a plugin that has higher version, Flutter will complain. However, you can silence this error in two ways - either by setting a higher platform version in ios/Podfile or by using another plugin that has higher version number and depends on the initial plugin (e.g. multiple Firebase plugins). This will usually let you run the app in debug mode without issues, but when you try to build an API, the build will fail saying it cannot find a plugin (and it will be the first one in an alphabetical order, most likely device_info).

All you have to do is set the higher iOS version in Xcode (not in Podfile):

Comment: Thank you for the information you shared, but I've done everything you said before i asked this question. I always get this error.

Comment: whats your ios deployment target version now?

Comment: It's 12.1, also in Xcode i selected 12.1

Comment: try it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/54599#issuecomment-644336055 https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/53573#issuecomment-749912604

Comment: Sorry still not resolved